Cannot decrypt private ED25519 key generated with cryptography Python module in ssh-keygen
1. Minimal Python code
import os
from stat import S_IRUSR
from stat import S_IWUSR

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ed25519
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import BestAvailableEncryption
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import PrivateFormat

if __name__ == "__main__":
    private=ed25519.Ed25519PrivateKey.generate()
    secret="123456".encode()

    a="./ed-pkcs8"
    with open(a, "wb") as f:
        contents=private.private_bytes(
            Encoding.PEM, 
            PrivateFormat.PKCS8,  # OpenSSH works. RSA works with both.
            BestAvailableEncryption(secret))
        f.write(contents)
    os.chmod(a, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)

2. Test and expectations with ssh-keygen
python keytest.py

ssh-keygen -y -f ed-pkcs8

(type 123456, press ENTER)
I expected the contents of the key to appear (unencrypted). Instead, I get the error message “Load key "ed-pkcs8": incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key.”
3. Alternatives that work

Replacing PrivateFormat.PKCS8 with PrivateFormat.OpenSSH. But then again a different format is generated, of course.
Generating an RSA (instead of ED25519).
If I reload the file in the Python cryptography module itself using the load_pem_private_key method (instead of using ssh-keygen).

What am I doing wrong? Is this an incompatibility of ssh-keygen with the module? Do I need to do something else? Thank you.
I may be on to something here but then again I am not familiar with OpenSSH so I can't comment.
(Versions)

Darwin laptop-david.local 24.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 24.1.0: Thu Oct 10 21:03:15 PDT 2024; root:xnu-11215.41.3~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
Python 3.13.0 [ cffi==1.17.1, cryptography==43.0.3, pycparser==2.22, bcrypt==4.2.0 ]
OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6 (notwithstanding limitations)


Reproduced on my Macbook Pro. Strangely, if I specify PKCS8 when generating an RSA key with ssh-keygen -m PKCS8 -t rsa I get an encrypted PKCS8 format. But if I do the same with ed25519 key, ssh-keygen -m PKCS8 -t ed25519, I get an openssh format private key, with no warning. It may be that, for some reason, ssh-keygen doesn't support encrypted PKCS8 ed25519 private keys.

Also, see this bug report.

Oh well, that what I was afraid of. Thanks for pointing me to the issue.
